# Can a non-EU Citizen holding an Austrian Resident Permit (Aufenthaltsbewilligung) work in Germany?

Tags: germany, austria

I moved to the Austria due to my wife's study in the Uni and I hold a long term Resident Permit in Austria. My question is "Can I find a job in Germany and receive a work permit from Germany?"

Comment: Not a full answer but your Austrian residence permit is mostly irrelevant. You cannot work in Germany solely based on this permit so while you can technically receive a German permit, you will need to qualify for the German permit according to the usual rules. The question is really whether you can receive a German work permit without residing in Germany (having a registered address, etc.) I don't know but it could be difficult.

Comment: Would this be a cross border activity? I.e still living in Austria, crossing daily to work in Germany?

Comment: @Relaxed if it's truly a long-term residence permit then getting a permit for Germany should be more or less a formality, shouldn't it?  But it doesn't seem likely that it's truly a long-term residence permit.

Comment: @phoog It makes a lot of things smoother but my understanding is that you would still need a job, or appropriate resources and health insurance (and to document all that), even accommodation can be required according to the directive. Conditions should be easier to meet than highly-skilled workers visa and the like, though, so not quite “the usual rules” I mentioned in my original comment.

Comment: There is a slight difference between the questions in the subject line and the text of your posting. With your Austrian residence permit, you can usually enter Germany for the purpose of job interviews, but not to work. That is, you can **find** work, but not **do** work. If you have a job offer, you can apply for a German work permit *from Austria*. If you get that, you can live and work in Germany.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I have interviewed with a German company in Germany and accepted to work. With the Austrian Aufenthaltsbewilligung, I should apply for the German Work permit in Austria and then receive wrok permit? Is it true? How is this process? Complicated or simple process? Thank you for your reply

Comment: The process will depend somewhat on the type of work / permit category you would be targeting but you still haven't answered a crucial question: Is this cross-border work (you reside with your wife in Austria, cross the border several times a week to physically work in Germany)? Will you move to Germany (you rent a place and register as a German resident)? Or some sort of remote position? Depending on the answer, getting a permit may be more difficult or even impossible.

Comment: I live with my family in the Austria. I want to work in Germany and rent a place in Germany and physically work in Germany. Is it possible to get the work permit from German authorities and move in Germany, while I only have the Austrian Aufenthaltsbewilligung? Thank you for your time.